# PHP (Laravel) undefined index error inside isset

Tags: php, laravel, isset

I've got a strange Laravel error today. The message is:
[image]

It clearly states that there is an undefined array index. However, when I looked at the rendered blade file mentioned here, and checked line 272 I got this:

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE[$_COOKIE['userhash'] . '-surgery'])): ?>
```

`$_COOKIE['userhash']` is always set. As seen on the above image, it's value is `70c0a3a1`. How is it possible that PHP (or Laravel) throws an error inside an isset statement? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Use `!empty` instead of [isset](http://php.net/isset). Read the documentation how both work.

Comment: The error you are looking at is error 3 out of 3. What does error 1/3 say? Usually fixing the first error will help solve the problem. You have to scroll further down the error page to get error 1/3.

Comment: Changing `isset` to `!empty` solved the problem... I did't aware that in php `isset` doesn't mean is set, but is not set to null, and fails on checking really unset values.

Answer (score 0):

Plese try this:

First you can check `($_COOKIE['userhash'])` is set or not as

```
isset($_COOKIE['userhash'])
```

Then you can try this :

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['userhash']) && isset($_COOKIE[$_COOKIE['userhash'] . '-surgery']))`
```

Comment: It's already checked a line above, and as my example shows `userhash` is set correctly. Your code does exactly the same thing as mine, and fails becaouse of the exact same reason...